# How to make react-router work with dynamically constructed string

Tags: string, reactjs, variables, dynamic, routes

I have a requirement to perform routing based on a dynamically constructed string. Something like "city-homestay-id" where "city" and "id" are dynamically replaced. How would I make it work with react-router.

Ex:
www.xxx.com/atlanta-homestay-12345

Thanks

Comment: Please go through : https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow . Please add more details on what you have tried already.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `<Route path="/:cityId" component={YourComponent} />` for dynamic routing and access Id in `YourComponent`

```
const { match: { params } } = this.props;
console.log(params.cityId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can I do something like